# Plotting patches of random shapes with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

This is my target to plot:
Several ellipses which are not regular shape.

[image]
<sub>(source: [clouddn.com](http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-12/7568305.jpg))</sub>

I was thinking about generating some random number as vertices location.

But it can only build a polygon. So, how to plot several arcs and make them close up?

Comment: The link to the jpg image doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

To create any arbitrary shape, you will need to use the [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon) class and just provide enough x,y samples to make it appear as smooth of a path as necessary (at the end of the day it's still straight line segments when you zoom in close enough).

If you only have a few points, you can use one of many [interpolation methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) (such as `scipy.interpolate.spline`) to create a smooth interpolant of the data that you can then feed to the `Polygon` constructor.

Here is a simple example creating a circle using the `Polygon` class by supplying x,y points around the circle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# Circle coordinates (100 points around the circle)
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(100,1)
coords = np.concatenate((np.cos(t), np.sin(t)), axis=1)

ax = plt.axes()

polygons = [];
polygons.append(Polygon(coords))
p = PatchCollection(polygons, alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sonds just like the example in the official documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html

the main part, they just construct a list of the ellipses:

```
ells = [Ellipse(xy=rnd.rand(2)*10, width=rnd.rand(), height=rnd.rand(), angle=rnd.rand()*360) for i in range(250)]
```

...or did I miss your point? :)

Comment: The original question states that they are *not* regular ellipses (also you can see this in the figure).